# Geocode with locationid as param is not providing result for a specific locationid - 'NT_9i7d-q6Hvc8hOg28FefIuD'

Tags: here-api

The locationid for which I am not getting the result is 'NT_9i7d-q6Hvc8hOg28FefIuD', which is India.

What I am doing is, I am getting suggestions from auto-complete api and using the locationid from there to fetch the lat and lng.

But for this specific locationid, I am not getting results.

EDIT:
This is the API query for suggestions from which I got the location id,

https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=&app_code=&beginHighlight=%3Cb%3E&endHighlight=%3C/b%3E&maxresults=20&query=India

And this is the API query to get lat, lng using location id

https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=&app_code=&locationid=NT_9i7d-q6Hvc8hOg28FefIuD

Comment: Please provide the api query you used which gave you the above location id. Also,the query you are using with this locationId to get lat,lng

Comment: This is the API query for suggestions from which I got the location id,

https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=<MY_APPID>&app_code=<MY_APP_CODE>&beginHighlight=%3Cb%3E&endHighlight=%3C/b%3E&maxresults=20&query=India

And this is the API query to get lat, lng using location id

https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=<MY_APPID>&app_code=<MY_APP_CODE>&locationid=NT_9i7d-q6Hvc8hOg28FefIuD

Comment: looks like a bug, as the second proposal from your autocomplete request, "United States, <b>India</b>na" gives locationid NT_LF5hvollz27GbPHZzrUR6A which can be geocoded correctly

Answer (score 0):

We shall report this internally and check if this is a bug. Meanwhile to unblock, you can try using geocode api instead of autocomplete.

Example

```
http://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?gen=8&jsonattributes=1&language=en-US&mapview=-23.476246%2C-46.5937408%3B-23.5025772%2C-46.5619834&maxresults=20&searchtext=India
```

This provides location id: NT_S5qTSISGGoR65nRJBNSK0D for India which works with your second query.

Comment: I just stumbled on this same bug, a year later with coincidentally the same autocomplete search term 'India' ... Does Here intend to fix this bug, and is there an issue on github or whatnot to track progress, or are we on our own with creating a robust workaround?

Comment: This bug has been fixed in June 2020.